# Ansible facts of all hosts to template

Tags: ansible, jinja2, dhcp

I'm trying to write a dhcpd.conf template for my server to set static leases that is looking like this atm:

`

```
{% for item in groups.all %}
{% set short_name = item.split('.') %}
host {{ item }} {
  hardware ethernet {{ ansible_eth0.macadress }};
  fixed-address {{ hostvars[item]['ipaddress'] }};
}
{% endfor %}
```

`

'ipaddress' is a variable set in the inventory file
After running the playbook everything works fine, but the value for 'ansible_eth0.macaddress' is always the same and not like expected the macaddress matching to the right host.

Does anyone have an idea how i can make the loop working like i want to?

Answer (score 0):

Without the tasks you use this jinja2 template i can just guess. Maybe u are fine with_subelements.

Comment: Task looks like this:`- name: template isc-dhcp-server dhcpd.conf
  template:
    src: ../templates/dhcpd.conf.j2
    dest: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
    backup: yes
  register: dhcpd_conf
`

Comment: Hey tobit. Can u add this to your description above. well formed for other participants? Maybe more people answering your question. :)